# Backup mysql data and upload to mongo db automatically in every 1 month

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, nosql

i have a requirement in my company, i have to took backup of registered user from mysql database and update it to mongodb database in every one month but if only user is active and if user is inactive than took backup in 15days and i have to manage logs of that also anyone have any refrence or website please share.

Note: i have to implement this functionality in existing project

technologies: mysql,mongodb,springboot 2.x,maven,spring data jpa

Comment: Enable Event Scheduler on MySQL. Create Event procedure which selects according data and saves in to CSV file. Upload this CSV file to Mongo and import.

Comment: Mysql dump, Also it might to use real backup tools

Comment: i want to do it through coding and automate that process

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.